# Unusual "border" around page showing up

Tags: html, css

For some reason there is an unusual border on my page. I'm unable to find the cause for it in the code:

http://danie1.me/temp/

Any idea how this can be fixed?

Answer (score 2):

You have to update your `<body>` styles like this:

```
body {
  color: green;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

And it's generally a good idea to use some kind of [CSS Reset](http://www.cssreset.com/) to avoid a lot of troubleshouting in different browsers.

Answer (score 0):

All elements by defauls has some style. Tag `body` by default has `margin` not 0. So

```
body { margin: 0px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your body has extra margins. It is better to use a CSS Reset, a simple one:

```
* {margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none;}
```

Or just to body:

```
body {margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none;}
```